# Need Slice layer of Caffe in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, caffe

I defined the following slice layer, where I want to split Nx7 into Nx3 and Nx4 two blobs

```
layers {
name: "slice_label"
type: SLICE
bottom: "label"
top: "label_pos"
top: "label_rotation"
slice_param {
    slice_dim: 1
    slice_point: 3
}
```

How can I do the same thing in Tensorflow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that you can do this with a hand-crafted layer, using the [split method](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/array_ops/slicing_and_joining#split).  You can also do it with separate calls to **slice**.  Something like

```
slice3, slice4 = tf.split(input_tensor, [3, 4], 1)
```

---

**Correction per OP comment:**

```
slice3, slice4 = tf.split_v(labels, [3, 4], 1)
```

BTW, the spacing follows PEP8 standards.  It's not required, of course, but there is checking software that prefers the spacing this way.

Comment: Great! This one works for me "slice3, slice4=tf.split_v(labels, [3,4], 1)". Please update your answer and I will mark it correct! Thanks!